# chrome captureVisibleTab capturing previous page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

This sends a base64 image data to the tab.

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab null, {}, (image) ->
  port.postMessage(image)
```

It is activated by content script, called as soon as the content script is executed.  In the manifest, the script is called on "document_end"

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["javascripts/main.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}],
```

Sometimes, this works.  Other times, it captures a completely black image.  When navigating, it will frequently load the new page, and then display a screenshot of the previous page.

I remember an excellent guide on how/when content scripts are executed, which seems to have been taken down.

What's the right way to get a proper onready here?

Comment: I also have the same problem (when openning several pages in bulk mode [right click on a bookmark folder] some pages are correctly captured and some stay black). Would anyone have at least the beginning of a solution, a bug description, etc? Thx, BN

Comment: I can recommend this page as kind of cool to read, but it doesn't address the issue: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome -.  I tried confirming good pageVisibilityState, but that didn't do enough. Perhaps try a `setTimeout`, as a way check what might be going on.